# Is it possible to install Tails on VirtualBox?

Tags: tails, virtual-machine

Is it possible to install Tails on VirtualBox ?
I know you could only boot it when you mount the ISO. And after you are logged in in Tails if you click Aplications > Tails > Tails installer it says "Could not find target device" even if you have space alocated for Tails in VM.

Comment: You'd need to make VirtualBox emulate a removable USB disk drive. Whether you can or cannot make VirtualBox do that is a question for VirtualBox.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about Tor, it's about VirtualBox.